# canvas react component flickers when resizing

Tags: reactjs, canvas, react-hooks, html5-canvas, drawimage

When I resize my canvas component it flickers. I am not quite sure why is this happening. The resizing happens when the canvas length and width changes.

Here is my component:

```
const Cargo = styled.canvas`
width: ${props => props.width}px;
height: ${props => props.height}px;
margin-left: ${props => props.marginLeft}px;
position: relative;
`;

const Canvas = () => {

const canvasRef = useRef(null);

useEffect(() => {
  const canvas = canvasRef.current;
  const img = new Image();
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  
  if(!canvas) {
    return;
  }
  const draw = () => {
    img.src = `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/images/${(cargoState.cargo_type).toLowerCase()}.jpg`;
    img.onload = function () {

    canvas.width = this.naturalWidth;
    canvas.height = this.naturalWidth;

    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0,  this.width, this.height);
    
  };
  }
  draw();

    
},[]);
  


return (
  <>
    <Cargo ref={canvasRef} style={{marginLeft: marginLeft}} height={cargoHeight} width={cargoWidth} />
  </>
)
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The flickering is due to two reasons:

1. Creating a new image in each drawing is an expensive operation, so it is best to use a reference, that has brought me a lot of optimization
2. The change in size can be felt somewhat abrupt, especially if it is done with the mouse wheel. So the best is to use requestAnimationFrame.

If you only perform step 1 there will be no flickering.

the code would look like this:

```
  const canvasRef = useRef(null);
  const requestRef = useRef();
  const image = useRef(null);
  const [cargoHeight, setCargoHeight] = useState(100);
  const [cargoWidth, setCargoWidth] = useState(100);

  const draw = () => {
    const canvas = canvasRef.current;
    const img = new Image();
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    canvas.width = image.current.width;
    canvas.height = image.current.height;
    ctx.drawImage(
      image.current,
      0,
      0,
      image.current.width,
      image.current.width
    );
  };

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    requestRef.current = requestAnimationFrame(draw);
    return () => window.cancelAnimationFrame(requestRef.current);
  }, [cargoHeight, cargoWidth]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <img
        src={
          "https://www.tuexperto.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/png.jpg.webp"
        }
        ref={image}
        style={{ display: "none" }}
      />
      <Cargo ref={canvasRef} height={cargoHeight} width={cargoWidth} />
      <button onClick={() => setCargoHeight(cargoHeight + 50)}>height</button>
      <button onClick={() => setCargoWidth(cargoWidth + 50)}>width</button>
    </div>
  );
```

A [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dawn-cookies-zhenw?file=/src/App.js:349-1576) with the solution and the complete example